# Problems when trying to submit iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm a fairly new developer.
When I try to submit my iphone app with xcode, I've got error as follows;

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

After searching, I found out that I have to create a Distribution Provisioning Profile. 
However, my distribution provisioning profile doesn't work, even though my Development Provisioning Profile works perfectly.

Could someone please help me with this problem?
I'm stuck all day...
and please forgive me that my English is not great.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed you distribution certificate (not the distribution profile) into KeyChain Access?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this [link](http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/build.html) should help you, it explains how to build for distribution.

If not then you should consider going into iOS provisionning portal and recreate your certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your project run on device based on the developer profile.

before your prepare the submission.just follow these things,

1. create  Distribution profile in developer.apple.com--> iOs provisioning portal.Download and install into your system and iosdevice.
   2.Then go to your project --> info Press + button above the comment-line build use.select any one of the that duplicate. and then rename that as "Distribution"
2. then select your project-->build settings  and target--> build settings set the  code sing as your distribution profile.

this is possible only to build.

then select your products section. right click on it select show in finder option and zip your .app file.

this file has to be use after your finish into the itunesconnect.apple.com ---> mange your applications selection.

go to the application loader--> select your .app zip file

this for submission of app store.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try what you suggest. If it doesn't work well, I will come back here. Thank you so much!

Comment: where now error acquired while you build or you submit to the app store.